# Spark streaming batch interval with Kenisis

Tags: spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

What is the effect of setting batch interval when creating the streaming context

> new StreamingContext(spark.sparkContext, batchInterval)

According to this Amazon [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/optimize-spark-streaming-to-efficiently-process-amazon-kinesis-streams/) the Kinesis batch interval is hard coded to 1s.

Answer (score 1):

The the Kinesis batch interval mentioned in the Blog is the interval at which the receiver reads data from a stream, which is by default set at 1 second. This interval just decides input rate of the receiver.

The batchInterval provided while creating the StreamingContext divides the input records into batches of given interval, to be processed by spark streaming.

For example if you have single Kinesis receiver and your batchInterval is 10 seconds then receiver would be able to read up to 10000 records in 10 second, that is reading 1000 records per second interval from the Kinesis stream. So your that streaming batch will include 10000 records.